# Magento log_visitor_online table not updating value on current time

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento  suppose customer login/logout But its value not updating on log_visitor_online table.

I have to fetch that whose online or offline for chat functionality.
Please anyone can reply for solution
Thanks

Comment: Hello guys, is there anyone who can tell me about it ?

Comment: Guys, i solved it...